# API dev : Advice for Unity to loopback http transfer process

Tags: c#, node.js, unity-game-engine, loopbackjs

I'm curently developing an API to be use from a multiplatform Unity game. I need to transfer data from the client to my databese server.

My question is relative to the client to server communication.
What is the best way to communicate?
- With fields
- With one raw data passing json object.

I'm using loopback.io

For now, I'm doing everything with field because my HTTP Plugin is doing wired stuff with my string during encoding and I don't succeed to read it with express.js.

I'am expected more advices about good pratice/ way to proceed

Here one of my receiver function with on my point of view way to many arguments.

```
  ApiElement.createSimpleElement = function(IdGameData, PositionX, PositionY, PositionZ, RotationY, RotationZ, Layer,
                                        Type, Gravity, Health, MoveSpeed, FireSpeed, cb) {
var data = FillElement(IdGameData, PositionX, PositionY, PositionZ, RotationY, RotationZ, Layer, Type, Gravity,
  Health, MoveSpeed, FireSpeed);
// Create the element
ApiElement.create(data, function(err, ApiElementInstance) {
  if (err) {
    cb(err, null);
  } else {
    console.log(ApiElementInstance);
    cb(null, ApiElementInstance);
  }
});
```

};

Answer (score 0):

I would go for creating a Model for each JSON body you want to represent.
As far as I can see in Loopback documentation you can tell the app to expose a custom model (e.g. a json with all the params you are passing in that function), this would make the code clearer and easier to mantain especially if you're going to use the model objects in many routes.
Hope this helps.

Reference: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Exposing-models-over-REST.html

Comment: Thank you, it’s exactly what I'm currently doing and I also fill it’s a good solution. My question was also about data transmission with post HTTP protocol. For now I’m using field and not JSON object to send my data because of BESTHTTP Unity plugin, this plugin replace “by \” for small JSON object. I don’t know if it’s the best solution.